# Retrieve all data from an inner join with duplicate column names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, php

I have a database with tables for "users" and "profiles".  Every profile links back to a user.  I would like to do an inner join where I am able to retrieve a set of profiles that meet a condition along with the user data associated with them. However some columns in both profiles and users have the same names.

Currently I have a few methods I know I could do:

- I know I can do a select * on profiles and then programmatically for each profile also select * on users for the user of the profile.
- I could also do an alias for the columns with duplicate names but this would require maintenance if I were to update the columns in the future.
- I could also require every column to have a unique name, but that feels like not a good solution either.

Is there a better way?  What is the best way to do this long term?

Per request, lets say the tables are defined as the following:

- Table users having columns of id, name
- Table profiles having columns
  of id, user_id, name

Comment: Use aliases. `SELECT t1.col1 AS t1c1, t2.col1 AS t2c1, ... FROM table AS t1 JOIN table AS t2 ...`. PS. Do not use an asterisk as "all columns" alias except COUNT(*), always type columns names one-by-one.

Comment: Could you provide your table definitions in your Post please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However some columns in both profiles and users have the same names.

Why do you think that would be a problem?
Specify the columns that you want to work with in every SQL query.
**Never** use `select *` in Production code.

To address your potential options:

> ... `select *` on profiles and then programmatically for each profile also `select *` on users ...

No, no, no and No.
This is a classic "1+N Query" Model and will perform *atrociously* badly as your table grows.
Just join the tables as you would do normally and give the columns useful aliases as you do so:

```
select 
  u.id as user_id 
, p.id as profile_id 
from users u 
inner join profiles p on u.id = p.u_id 
where ...
```

> ... do an alias for the columns with duplicate names ... would require maintenance if I were to update the columns in the future.

... *only* if you change the columns that are involved in *this* query.
This is *totally normal* and you should *expect* to be doing this if your database is going to "be around" for any length of time.

> ... require every column to have a unique name ...

Actually, this is probably quite a Good Idea (making your data elements completely atomic) but it's [almost] completely unenforceable.
Databases are intrinsically *shared entities* and you will wind up with any number of people mucking about with any amount of stuff whenever they want/need to.

Comment: ***Never** use `select *` in Production code.* – except when it's part of an `EXISTS` check, where `SELECT *` is perfectly fine, although some people do prefer replacing the `*` there as well, e.g. `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...)`, `EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ...)` etc.